# Unable to initialise vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to initialise vault with below command, running the command with root using,
also tried with 'vault' user. owner of the `/etc/vault` directory set to vault user but getting the same error with vault user as well.

```
vault operator init > /etc/vault/config/init.file
```

But failing with below error:

```
root@ip-172-31-65-238:~# vault operator init > /etc/vault/config/init.file 
Error initializing: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/init
Code: 400. Errors:

* failed to initialize barrier: failed to persist keyring: mkdir /etc/vault/data/core: read-only file system
```

My vault config file looks like below:

```
listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = "1"
}
api_addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
storage "file" {
    path = "/etc/vault/data"
}
ui = true
```

I have exported environment variable as below:

```
export VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
```

My systemd file looks like below:

```
[Unit]
Description=vault service
Documentation=https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/vault/config/default.hcl

[Service]
User=vault
Group=vault
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=read-only
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
SecureBits=keep-caps
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK
Capabilities=CAP_IPC_LOCK+ep
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYSLOG CAP_IPC_LOCK
NoNewPrivileges=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vault server -config=/etc/vault/config/default.hcl -log-level=info
ExecReload=/bin/kill --signal HUP \$MAINPID
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGINT
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStopSec=30
StartLimitIntervalSec=60
StartLimitBurst=3
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough information about your environment but you might have some issue regarding the file permissions.

Someone had a similar problem in a Google Cloud server - it had to do with a missing "read_write" service-account scope, as you can see here: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/6085

Comment: yeah it worked when I executed with root without adding a vault user

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have created the vault user. otherwise, change the user in your service file. and update ProtectHome=read-write vaule.

```
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=read-write
```

and then create the file manually.

```
mkdir -p /etc/vault/data/core
```